# Subset finder for different set lengths

Tags: algorithm, math

Question: You need to write an algorithm that finds the number of subarrays in a given integer array whose sum is equal to a target number. Write a function that calculates the count of subarrays whose sum equals the target number.

Example:
Input:
Array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
Target Sum: 8

Output:
Count of Subarrays:4 ([6,2],[5,3],[5,2,1],[4,3,1])

note: you can solve it in any programming language you want
note: the function should be suitable for different set lengths

Comment: This is the problem definition. But what is your question for us? ("Solve my homework for me" does not count.)

Comment: The problem is that I have to write n loops for each n-element subset, but for a 1000-element set this solution becomes impractical.
this is not a homework it's an algorithm question chatgpt asked me
 @Berthur

Comment: Are you familiar with dynamic programming?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with it but if my problem is going to be solved by dynamic programming I would love to learn dynamic programming. I would appreciate it if you could suggest a source for me. Thank you. @MBo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic programming approach:

Make array/list `A[]` of size `Sum+1`

Fill it with zeros, except for `A[0]=1`  (there is one way to make empty subset)

```
for every value V from array:
    for every index i from Sum downto V:
         A[i] += A[i-V]
print A[Sum]
```

What's happen:

Array `A[]` holds number of subsets for all possible sums (you can inspect it's contents after every round of outer loop).

We can make sum `i` using item `V` and any subsets with sum `i-V`.

Reverse scan - to avoid double counting of the same item.